# Access related object after save

Tags: django, django-models

I need to get Question after Answer is saved.

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    # ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(Answer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        # I need to get question object here
        q = self.question.get()
```

And Question

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer,
                               related_name='question',
                               blank=True,
                               null=True)
```

They are related through a foreign key. If I try `answer.question.get()` I get that it doesn't exist. If I try to get Question by `answer_id` it doesn't find anything either as if question wasn't updated yet (but I can get it later). Any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't your relationship be the otherway round?  Right now an answer can have many questions. Sure 4, is a n answer to 2+2? and 2*2 but surely a question with many answers or exactly one answer is a better way to model this?

Comment: I agree, this could be done better. But I didn't make this, just trying to fix it

Comment: Do you have to retrieve the question inside `save()` method? What's the difference for you if you retrieve it after `save()` method?

Comment: It's an API call, and the save method is called implicitly. No exactly sure how though

Answer (score 0):

One question can have many answers, so its 1-M relation from `Question` to `Answer`. So need to define the `ForeignKey` in `Answer` model.

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    # ...
    question = models.ForeignKey(Answer,
                               related_name='answers',
                               blank=True,
                               null=True)
```

And in `save` method you can get the question simply by accessing the attribute `question` like this

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    # ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(Answer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        q = self.question
```

And also an `Answer` should always be for a `Question`, so `blank=True, null=True` should not be there in `ForeignKey` question.

Comment: I know that's how it should be, but I can't change models. I'm trying to fix this project (already live) and it makes me want to jump out the window...

Comment: if thats the case then simply use `q = self.question.all()`, this will return all questions for the answer as per existing models relations.

Comment: I tried that already, I get an empty array. At that point question doesn't have answer_id saved yet.